# Jenkins python api authentication "403 forbidden"

Tags: python, jenkins, urllib2

I'm trying to use [jenkinsapi python library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi) to work with Jenkins. My Jenkins is setup to authenticate with LDAP (with [Active Directory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin)). However, when I run my script to authenticate I fails (actually it ran once, but since then I get 403 Forbidden error every time)

it fails from the start:

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
j = Jenkins("https://qaa.server.com/jenkins", "username", "password")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse-SDK-4.2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1392, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\eclipse-SDK-4.2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1085, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "C:\work\selenium-project\ses-web\utils\mark_slave_offline.py", line 10, in <module>
    j = Jenkins("https://qaa.server.com/jenkins", "username", "password")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi-0.1.11-py2.7.egg\jenkinsapi\jenkins.py", line 43, in __init__
    JenkinsBase.__init__(self, baseurl, formauth=formauth)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi-0.1.11-py2.7.egg\jenkinsapi\jenkinsbase.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.poll()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi-0.1.11-py2.7.egg\jenkinsapi\jenkinsbase.py", line 41, in poll
    self._data = self._poll()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi-0.1.11-py2.7.egg\jenkinsapi\jenkinsbase.py", line 45, in _poll
    return retry_function(self.RETRY_ATTEMPTS , self.get_data, url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi-0.1.11-py2.7.egg\jenkinsapi\utils\retry.py", line 39, in retry_function
    raise e
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

what's interesting is that the **following code works just fine *every time***:

```
def urlopen(url,username=None, password=None, data=None):
    '''Open a URL using the urllib2 opener.'''
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    return response

result = urlopen('https://qaa.server.com/jenkins', "username", "password")
```

QUESTION: Why is the Jenkins code failing? Could it be the apache server misconfigured?

thanks!

**UPDATE:** This is what I'm getting as a responce

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/jenkins/loginfrom=%2Fjenkins%2Fapi%2Fpython%2F'/>
        <script>window.location.replace('/jenkins/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2Fapi%2Fpython%2F');
        </script>
    </head>
<body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>Authentication required</body>
</html>
```

Apache access.log: `- [07/Sep/2012:15:24:21 -0400] "GET /jenkins/api/python/ HTTP/1.1" 403 593`

UPDATE: error.log at debug mode:

```
.....
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1897): OpenSSL: read 160/160 bytes from BIO#e08150 [mem: e96ea5] (BIO dump follows)
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1830): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0000: 64 c2 ac 70 d0 d6 22 02-ef 56 98 32 6e 16 20 53  d..p.."..V.2n. S |
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0010: 84 fb 94 c7 51 a4 a8 9c-b3 8f 48 c8 84 1e 46 6b  ....Q.....H...Fk |
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0020: 15 c9 f4 cb ef cf 38 ed-a1 8b 41 08 a6 3b 95 f0  ......8...A..;.. |
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0030: bd b3 05 ef 68 68 e0 fb-52 92 ad fc 7f aa 72 50  ....hh..R.....rP |
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0040: 9e d9 7d 98 18 82 eb 07-bb 45 e3 e5 b2 93 6d 34  ..}......E....m4 |
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0050: fe 18 b5 d4 5c c9 78 c9-78 0c 6b cb 50 80 96 6d  ....\\.x.x.k.P..m |
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0060: 49 8a 39 b2 73 b2 ae 76-a4 d3 50 7a 38 a7 54 72  I.9.s..v..Pz8.Tr |
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0070: 41 e5 13 b2 1f 71 a1 b0-db 89 81 4f 14 3a 93 18  A....q.....O.:.. |
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0080: 5a e0 0e 9e c9 d9 1e f3-01 53 eb 08 dc 23 89 fd  Z........S...#.. |
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0090: a0 13 81 ac 26 55 54 fd-22 64 7e 37 f3 cd 2d af  ....&UT."d~7..-. |
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1875): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 63 (server qaa.server.com:443)
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(56): proxy: HTTP: canonicalising URL //localhost:8180/jenkins/api/python/
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1506): [client 207.***.***.1*2] proxy: http: found worker http://localhost:8180/jenkins for http://localhost:8180/jenkins/api/python/
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] mod_proxy.c(1015): Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1973): proxy: HTTP: serving URL http://localhost:8180/jenkins/api/python/
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(2011): proxy: HTTP: has acquired connection for (localhost)
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(2067): proxy: connecting http://localhost:8180/jenkins/api/python/ to localhost:8180
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(2193): proxy: connected /jenkins/api/python/ to localhost:8180
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(2444): proxy: HTTP: fam 2 socket created to connect to localhost
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(2576): proxy: HTTP: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:8180 (localhost)
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1743): proxy: start body send
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1847): proxy: end body send
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(2029): proxy: HTTP: has released connection for (localhost)
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1884): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
[Fri Sep 07 16:52:09 2012] [info] [client 207.***.***.1*2] Connection closed to child 63 with standard shutdown (server qaa.server.com:443)
```

Comment: What is the source of the error: Apache, LDAP or Jenkins?  Have you checked the logs?

Comment: @stark I've updated what I get as a response. So it looks like authentication is not even tried?

Comment: What's in the Apache error log?

Comment: @stark `ipaddress [07/Sep/2012:15:24:21 -0400] "GET /jenkins/api/python/ HTTP/1.1" 403 593`

Comment: Ok. Then your problem is that your error log looks just like your access log.

Comment: @stark Sorry, that was my access.log. Error.log has nothings. it is set at LogLevel warn.

Comment: @stark I added the error.log at LogLevel debug

Comment: @Alex did you ever solve this? I'm suffering the same problem.

Comment: @KomodoDave, the solution is to use different module. I've posted the answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins: HTTP error 403 when getting config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462620/jenkins-http-error-403-when-getting-config)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution for this problem is to use different [python-jenkins module](http://packages.python.org/python-jenkins/)

With this module everything works fine:

```
import jenkins
j = jenkins.Jenkins(base_url, username, password)
```

Comment: @KomodoDave, no problem. The deeper problem with `jenkinsapi` module and their authentication seems to be in how they created the request with auth header. But that's deeper that I was willing to research.

Comment: Completely understandable. Since it's so trivial to simply decode the json from `http://yourjenkins/api/json` I decided to go that way. This makes for a script with no dependencies either, which is a good thing. But I wanted to understand whether I was doing something silly wrong, hence asking you for how you solved the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: one more hint, the password could be a token instead of real password, token can be got from user's profile

Answer (score 0):

Since `jenkinsapi` leverages `urllib2` you can use an opener to handle the authentication.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24048578/1733117