# Jenkins: HTTP error 403 when getting config

Tags: python, jenkins

I try to update Jenkins jobs' config programmatically, and the [python Jenkins api](http://packages.python.org/jenkinsapi/index.html) looked ok, but I can't retrieve a config because of HTTP error 403 (forbidden):

```
from jenkinsapi import api
j = api.Jenkins('https://server.test.com/hudson', 'fp12210', 'xxxxxxxx')
job = j.get_job('BBB-100-CheckStatusAll')
conf = job.get_config()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Adding user and password in URL, [as mentionned in another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427557/jenkins-and-github-webhook-http-403), fails too:

```
 j = api.Jenkins('https://fp12210:xxxxxxxx@server.test.com/hudson')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\jenkinsapi\utils\retry.py", line 39, in retry_function
    raise e
InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: 'xxxxxxxx@server.test.com/hudson'
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the web api directly? Something like `curl -u "fp12210:xxxxx" https://server.test.com/hudson/job/BBB-100-CheckStatusAll/config.xml`. Maybe the problem isn't on the python side of things.

Comment: Well the second method isn't going to work because the library needs to handle that format of URL correctly. For example, browsers 64 encode the username and password and stick them in as headers before sending the actual request. It looks like the Jenkins api library you're using doesn't do that and instead includes them in the url :(

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24048578/1733117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635113/python-urllib2-basic-http-authentication-and-tr-im) is the solution. I now get an error 500, but this is another story...

Comment: That awkward moment when the solution to your problem... is _another_ problem ._.

Answer (score 0):

The [python jenkins api](http://packages.python.org/jenkinsapi/index.html) uses `urllib2`.

You can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24048578/1733117 for using preemptive basic authentication, or retry with basic authentication when you get a `403` (e.g. anonymous user has limited access).